# Cannot launch 64 bit version of R on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, r, windows-10-v2004

I am unable to start **64 bit version of R** on windows 10 - I am not getting any error message. If I start directly R.exe/Rterm.exe only blank terminal windows appears (32 bit version works fine), if I open the GUI, it freezes for a while and then just disappear. I was unable to find anything relevant on the internet (not that surprising since the problem is not specific enough).

I have tried installing both 4.0.2 and 3.6.3 versions (first one, then uninstalling before installing the older version) but the results is still the same - 32 bit **works**, 64 bit does not). I have tried removing the configuration files in AppData but it also did not work. I am running Windows 10 64-bit (Version **2004**, build **20197.1000**). I had not a similar problem on any other machine I have installed R in the past.

I am aware that this is not a good description but I am unsure what other details should I provide or where else to look for an answer to the problem, I will be happy for any suggestion how to solve it.

Comment: Is your Windows 10 version 64-bit? I assume it might be, but you did not say. That is one reason.  Second, try the installation on a production version of Windows 10. The version how have is newest Insider Version. The app may need to be upgraded for the next Windows version.

Comment: @John Yes, the system is 64-bit (I have edited the question to reflect that information). Yes, I know that it is the latest Insider Version (that is the reason I have made the build version bold). I had not ever had similar problem on a production version, however, I have not had a similar problem with any other app on the preview version. I know that it might be caused by the insider preview, however, I do need the insider preview for few functions that are vital for me. Thank you for your input though. Do you have any other ideas I could try besides waiting for production version?

Comment: The current version of the app is apparently not compliant with the version of Windows. I have seen this (with other apps) on my own Windows Insider machine here.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was afraid of. Do you want to make an answer confirming that it is not compliant so I can accept it?

Comment: I have posted an answer for you. Thanks

Comment: @VladimírKunc - any luck with this? Enterprise versions of Windows 10/11 do not seem to be able to run 64 bit versions of R greater than 4.0.2. I still have this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the installation on a production version of Windows 10.

The version you have here is newest Insider Version.

The app may need to be upgraded for the next Windows version. I have a Windows Insider machine with this current build here and I have see apps that had to be upgraded to accommodate the new version.