# R Versions 4.0.3+ 64 bit Refuses to Launch on Windows 10

Tags: r, rstudio

Repost of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550403/r-versions-4-0-3-64-bit-refuse-to-launch-on-windows-10) question on stack overflow

After updating R to 4.0.3, and now 4.0.4, I am unable to launch the 64-bit version. The 32-bit version works fine and previous releases work fine in 64-bit.

Launching in RStudio fails as well as running the Rgui directly.

I have seen a lot of posts relating to version issues with Windows 10 [example](https://superuser.com/questions/1580283/cannot-launch-64-bit-version-of-r-on-windows-10). I am on Enterprise version 1909, OS build 18363.1379 and am unable to update the Windows 10 version I have.

I have uninstalled R and RStudio as well as doing a clean reinstall of windows.
I also do not get any error messages or warnings, just a crash or a "Failed to start"

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I belive this is a Windows **Enterprise** problem.  Have you found a solution yet?  I've had the same problem since about the time your posted this, yet I  still have not found a solution